# How to add a profile field in page--user.tpl.php

Tags: 7, theming

I need to put a profile field in page--user.tpl.php.

I try this :

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $user;
  $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);
  $variables['myfield'] = '';
  $myfield = $user->field_myfield;
  if($myfield) {
    $variables['myfield'] = $myfield['und'][0]['safe_value'];
  }
}
```

But i have an error :

```
Notice : Undefined property: stdClass::$field_myfield dans THEME_preprocess_page()
```

Do you know where should come the problem ?

Comment: I think you should use $user_fields->field_myfield

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, i have now an other error : `Notice : Undefined index: safe_value dans THEME_preprocess_page()`

Answer (score 0):

try using field_get_items()

```
$field_myfield = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_myfield');
$myfield_value = field_view_value('user', $user, 'field_myfield', $field_myfield[0]);
$variables['myfield'] = render($myfield_value);
```

More info [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7) and [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

Comment: If user is anonymous $field_myfield is false and $field_myfield[0] returns an error.

Comment: if that can be the case, just surround the code with an if statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
  global $user;
  $user_full = user_load($user->uid);

  // option 1
  $field_items = field_get_items("user", $user_full, 'field_myfield');
  if ($field_items) {
    $variables['myfield_value'] = $field_items[0]['safe_value'];
  }

  // option 2
  $variables['my_renderable_field'] = field_view_field("user", $user_full, 'field_myfield');
```

**EDIT:**

If you are going with option 2 it can be printed in your tpl file like this:

```
<?php print render($my_renderable_field); ?>
```

Also note that [field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) can take a view mode as parameter which is helpful if you want to display it in the tpl file in a manner different to what you specified in the user display settings for the default view mode.

Comment: Thanks J. Reynolds, the field does not appear, only "Array" appears. Otherwise, it seems to me that it returns the profile of the current user, and not the user corresponding to the consulted profile... I don't find how to make.

Comment: If it is option 2 you are referring to that will be the case when an anonymous user is viewing the page as an anonymous user does not have a profile. Rendering option 2 for an anonymous user with render() will just not print anything.

Comment: It returns the profile of the current user, not the user corresponding to the consulted profile... I try `$user_full = user_load(arg(1))`, it works, but i have sometimes this error : `Trying to get property of non-object in user_uri() (line 194 of /www/htdocs/modules/user/user.module)`

Comment: global $user; returns the currently logged in user in part. user_load($user->uid) then returns the currently logged in user's full profile. If you know the users uid that you want to load, then just take out global $user; and substitute the user id in user_load(the_users_id)